# MySQL Group By with top N number of each kind

Tags: mysql, group-by, ranking

I have a table like this:

```
Rank      Letter
1         A
2         A
3         B
4         A
5         C
6         A
7         C
8         C
9         B
10        C
```

And I need the top 2 of each letter ordered by ascending rank:

```
Rank      Letter
1         A
2         A
3         B
5         C
7         C
9         B
```

How would I do it? It's fairly straightforward to get just the top 1 using GROUP BY, but I can't seem to get it working for multiple entries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select distinct rank, letter
  from table1 t2
 where rank in 
         (select top 2 rank
            from table1 t2 
           where t2.letter = t1.letter 
           order by rank)
       order by letter, rank
```

EDIT: (my first try won't work on MySql (Quassnoi comment), I modified it to work on sql server for example)

second try:

```
select t.letter, t.rank
from table1 t
join (
    select t1.letter, min(t1.rank) m
    from table1 t1
    join (select t0.letter, min(t0.rank) m, count(1) c 
           from table1 t0 group by t0.letter) t2
    on t1.letter = t2.letter and ((t2.c = 1) or (t2.c > 1 and t1.rank > m))
    group by t1.letter) t3 
  on t.letter = t3.letter and t.rank <= t3.m
```

Comment: sorry, I work more with sql server. Now I have to find another solution for mysql and different from yours ;)

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT  mo.Letter, md.Rank
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT letter
        FROM    mytable
        ) mo
JOIN    mytable md
ON      md.Letter >= mo.Letter
        AND md.Letter <= mo.Letter
        AND Rank <=
        COALESCE
                (
                (
                SELECT  Rank
                FROM    mytable mi
                WHERE   mi.letter = mo.letter
                ORDER BY
                        Rank
                LIMIT 1, 1
                ),
                0xFFFFFFFF
                )
```

You need to have a composite index on `(Letter, Rank)` (in this order)

Note this construct:

```
md.Letter >= mo.Letter
AND md.Letter <= mo.Letter
```

instead of mere `md.Letter = mo.Letter`

It forces `Range checked for each record` which is more efficient.

See this article in my blog:

- [**Advanced row sampling**](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/06/advanced-row-sampling/)

for more details on this.

Comment: I'm getting an error of "#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row" due to the LIMIT 2 on the last subquery, do you know why this might be?

Comment: This is an old answer, but I found it useful.  I did however find that it doesn't quite work as expected.  If there are less than 2 instances of a letter, e.g., it won't return any of them.  You can add something like this: OR 
        (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM    mytable mi
        WHERE   mi.letter = mo.letter
        ) <= 2)
;

Comment: @Quassnoi excellent -- I like your version better than mine, thanks :)