# Is it possible to condense these queries into one?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, with one containing records referencing the other:

```
Goal
  id (int)
  name (text)
  value_mask (text)

GoalStatus
  id (int)
  goal (int)
  created (datetime)
  value (text)

Goal.id == GoalStatus.goal
```

What I'd like to do, is pull the latest record from the GoalStatus table, for each record in Goal. At the moment the only way I know how to do this is by making a separate query for each record in Goal (pseudocode):

```
goals = db.query("SELECT * FROM Goal")

foreach (goals as goal):
    goalStatus = db.query("
        SELECT * FROM GoalStatus
        WHERE goal = " + goal.id + "
        ORDER BY created DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ")
```

Is there a way of condensing this, so I'm not making an extra query for each Goal?

Comment: i think what you want is like :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537606/mysql-group-by-with-top-n-number-of-each-kind

Comment: and another link help : go to mysql part http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the per-group-maximum question. It's a very common thing to want to do that SQL doesn't make easy, so it gets asked a lot.

[Here's a summary](http://kristiannielsen.livejournal.com/6745.html) of approaches you can take. They'll have different performance attributes, and can behave differently when there are two rows sharing the same value as the maximum.

As a default first approach I would tend to go for a null-left-join rather than a subquery:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Goal
JOIN GoalStatus AS Gs0 ON Gs0.goal=Goal.id
LEFT JOIN GoalStatus AS Gs1 ON Gs1.goal=Goal.id AND Gs1.created>Gs0.created
WHERE Goal.id=(someid)
AND Gs1.id IS NULL
```

that is to say, join rows where there is no other row that has a greater `created` value.

Comment: That link was great. I couldn't really get your example to work but the first method on that page worked for me - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
      g.*,
      gs.id GoalStatusID,
      gs.created,
      gs.value
   from 
      goal g inner join goalstatus gs
          on g.id = gs.goal
   where 
      gs.created in 
          ( select max( gs2.created )
               from goalstatus gs2
               where g.id = gs2.goal )
```

Comment: I ended up using something similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

You could join on GoalStatus where there is no other goal status with the same goal id that has a greater created date.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Goal 
    INNER JOIN GoalStatus on Goal.GoalId=GoalStatus.GoalId 
WHERE Not Exists(SELECT * 
                 FROM GoalStatus innerGs 
                 WHERE innerGs.GoalId=Goal.GoalId 
                     and innerGs.created > GoalStatus.created)
```

Pretty ugly and will probably perform poorly but all I could think of.