# Complicated MySQL Query with distinct

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Here is the table I am getting the data from "actually it's a view of two different tables"

- The first table is the users table the holds everything about the user.
- The second is a log table that logs who viewed the video and when they viewed it.

  ```
  log_views.id,
  log_views.user_id,
  log_views.video_id,
  log_views.date,
  users.user_key,
  users.name_display,
  users.img_key
  ```

What I am trying to is display the last 18 users to view a video but I don't want any duplicate users. So if a user shows up twice in the last 18 I only want his latest view and then skip all the others.

I tried using the `DISTINCT` keyword but I am getting more than one column so it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these for some pointers:

[MySQL Group By with top N number of each kind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537606/mysql-group-by-with-top-n-number-of-each-kind)

http://explainextended.com/2009/03/06/advanced-row-sampling/

Answer (score 0):

This is what i ended up using.
`recent_video_viewers` is the name of the view I made so i didn't have to do any joins

```
SELECT id, MAX(date), user_id, img_key, random_key 
FROM recent_video_viewers 
WHERE video_id = '$vr[id]' AND img_key != '' 
GROUP BY user_id 
ORDER BY MAX(date) DESC 
LIMIT 18
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query that works. It assume that you need logs only for a given video id (@video_id):

```
SELECT log_date, user_id, name_display
FROM (
  SELECT MAX(l.date) AS log_date, user_id
  FROM log_views AS l
  WHERE (l.video_id=@video_id)
  GROUP BY user_id
  ORDER BY log_date DESC
  LIMIT 18
) AS top
INNER JOIN users AS u ON (u.user_key=top.user_id)
```