# How to select one row only?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables

```
   NAME
   +----+---------+
   | id |   name  |
   +----+---------+
   |  1 |   ABC   |
   |  2 |   CCC   |
   +----+---------+

   TBL_STATUS
   +----+-----------+--------+
   | id |  name_id  | status |
   +----+-----------+--------+
   |  1 |     1     |   KU   |
   |  2 |     1     |   HP   |
   |  3 |     1     |   HK   |
   |  4 |     2     |   KU   |
   |  5 |     2     |   HP   |
   +----+-----------+--------+
```

I select and join together (INNER JOIN) this 2 tables.
This is the result for my query.

```
   +---------+--------+
   |   name  | status |
   +---------+--------+
   |   ABC   |   HK   |
   |   ABC   |   HP   |
   |   ABC   |   KU   |
   |   CCC   |   HP   |
   |   CCC   |   KU   |
   +---------+--------+
```

Each name can have 3 status. HK, HP, or KU.
I want only a row for each name for the latest status.
For example:

```
   +---------+--------+
   |   name  | status |
   +---------+--------+
   |   ABC   |   HK   |
   |   CCC   |   HP   |
   +---------+--------+
```

Status priority should display with HK first (if any),
then if no HK display HP, and so on..

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537606/mysql-group-by-with-top-n-number-of-each-kind

Comment: I have __this__, I have __that__. Now write the `code` for me.

Comment: Can you define _latest_ status?

Comment: ***First*** In input tables you don't have dates, however in output table you have data. ***Second*** you have not shown what you have tried so far. Without your effort, no one on SO will be ready to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right tracks with your final output of

```
   +----+---------+--------+
   | id |   name  | status |
   +----+---------+--------+
   |  1 |   ABC   |   HK   | -- Need to remove
   |  2 |   ABC   |   HP   | -- Need to remove
   |  3 |   ABC   |   KU   |
   |  5 |   CCC   |   HP   | -- Need to remove
   |  6 |   CCC   |   KU   | 
   +----+---------+--------+
```

you just need to limit this to the max ID for each name, which is achieved in the below using an `INNER JOIN` on an aggregate query.

```
SELECT  Name, Status
FROM    Name
        INNER JOIN tbl_Status
            ON tbl_Status.Name_ID = Name.ID
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  MAX(ID) AS MaxStatusID
            FROM    Tbl_Status
            GROUP BY Name_ID
        ) MaxStatus
            ON MaxStatusID = tbl_Status.ID
```

Comment: This won't work if the ordering is ever different. I.e. something that was KU becomes HP.

Comment: @llion It won't even work corretly given the current data. It seems the OP wants the statuses in alphabetical order, so I could have just written `SELECT Name, MAX(Status) AS Status FROM Name INNER JOIN Status ON Name.ID = Status.Name_ID GROUP BY Name` which would returned the right results,, but would only work in one specific scenario. However the OP asked for the **logic** (in an earlier revision) behind limiting the result set to one row per name. This seemed the neatest way of demonstrating the standard technique where the `ROW_NUMBER()` function is not available.

Answer (score 0):

You must find max(id) from `TBL_STATUS` and then connect all data together eg.:

```
SELECT n.name, st3.status 
FROM name AS n 
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT st1.name_id, MAX(st1.id) AS max_id
     FROM TBL_STATUS st1 
     GROUP BY name_id) AS st2
  ON n.id=st2.name_id
LEFT JOIN 
  TBL_STATUS st3
  ON st2.max_id = st3.id
```

Comment: let just ignore the date, because I want to know the logic. of course I have tried, this is just a part of my problem in this query.

Comment: Change your `LEFT JOIN`s for `INNER JOIN`s. Otherwise you will end up with 5 rows in the output, but in 3 of them the status will be `NULL`.