# fetch first 10 records of each customer

Tags: mysql

I have a transaction table where I store the records of each customer's transactions.

Requirement : Is there any way to fetch all customers first 10 records based on his transaction date.

What I tried is : I tried using group by and then limit 10. but does not give the result which I need.

Comment: include whatever code you have written in the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Group By with top N number of each kind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537606/mysql-group-by-with-top-n-number-of-each-kind)